# How to log into CUPS admin with Debian "rootless" system?

Tags: debian, root, cups, printing, non-root-user

When I installed Debian 12, I was given the option to not allow root logins. Instead, the system lets me use su each time I need to do some minor maintenance.

When I go to http://localhost:631/, however, the login to administor passwords doesn't work. I tried username + password and "root" + password for usually sudo-ing, but neither worked.

How can I log into CUPS on Debian to administer my printers when root access is disabled?

Comment: With no guarantee of any sort : Try editing /etc/cups/cupsd.conf, find teh plave were  SystemGroup is defined. It should show some group name. Normally lpadmin. If it shows lpadmin then simply add root (user) to the lpadmin group. If it shows nothing then add lpadmin, eventually create the lpadmin group and add root in the lpadmin group.

Comment: Rather than add `root`, I  believe the commentor means add `sudo user` to `lpadmin' Usually adding the user to the `lp` group will work no matter what.

Answer (score 10):

from [`cups-files.conf(5)`](https://manpages.debian.org/cups-daemon/cups-files.conf.5#SystemGroup):

> `SystemGroup` *group-name [ ... group-name ]*
>
> Specifies the group(s) to use for @SYSTEM group authentication. The
> default contains "admin", "lpadmin", "root", "sys", and/or "system".

The `cups-daemon` package on Debian ships with a default for `/etc/cups/cups-files.conf` of:

> ```
> SystemGroup root lpadmin
> ```

(most probably from [compilation](https://salsa.debian.org/printing-team/cups/-/blob/debian/bookworm/debian/rules?ref_type=heads#L61) [options](https://salsa.debian.org/printing-team/cups/-/blob/debian/bookworm/conf/cups-files.conf.in?ref_type=heads#L19))

One can authenticate with an user in this group on the web page to gain administrative privileges through the CUPS GUI.

So this will be enough:

```bash
sudo adduser $USER lpadmin
```

Now after being authenticated using `$USER` and its password in the web session (even if authentication has already been done in the current web session and led to a *Forbidden* message), the administrative web menus are accessible (logout/login of the desktop user is not even needed: this is over TCP, so there's no local user credential considered, only the target user is considered).